# Any reason I'd get a NullReference exception on Windows 7 only?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, windows-7, windows-xp

My C#, .NET 4, app runs fine on XP (media centre to be exact - don't ask).

On Windows 7, it installs fine, but immediately borks. It complains about a NullReferenceException in the callback of a background worker. (I'd love to give you more information, but short of installing VS on the target machine, this is all I can get.)

So, anything I should know about deploying to Windows 7?

**Edit:** As requested, here's a better description of what's going on... When the main form of my app initialises, it uses a background worker to create an instance of a logging class. When the logging class is created, the worker's callback uses the log instance to add a new entry.

Comment: try w/o UAC? -----

Comment: Henk that sounds more like an answer and one I forgot to even consider. I would up vote you.

Comment: Is your app trying to access resources with elevated permissions? As @Henk says... UAC can be very unfriendly.

Comment: The logger class is basically an interfact to EventLog - could this cause UAC nasties?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like I commented, this is most likely a case of privileges (and it will break on Vista too).

It should be OK to *write* to an eventlog, but a restricted (normal) user cannot *create* an EventLog.

You may be able to workaround by pre-creating the EventLog with another Tool. But some (XP-minded) software thinks it's a good idea to always create the Log. Wrong.

Standard solution is to create the source from your setup.exe

Comment: Thanks Henk, I think this is probably it.

Comment: Hate to be a pest Henk, but do you think you might look at this subsequent question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176502/will-this-code-create-an-eventlog-at-installation-time

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a resource that can't be created. Do you happen to have a stacktrace or a better description of what this app actually does?

Comment: @Tom, why no stack trace? Because that would be superhelpful.

Comment: Because I'm an idiot and didn't grab one when I had access to the Windows 7 machine. :)